# How to insert data from two different tables using trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

I have two tables with data.  Now I have to insert selected fields of these two tables into a third table.

Table 1 will return me 1 row only.
Table 2 will have 5 records (say).

Now Table 3 should have 5 records with data from table 1 and table 2.

Is there a way of looping sql server trigger.  Please answer my query as soon as possible.

Thanks and Regards.

Comment: Please describe why you need a trigger. And please answer as soon as possible!

Comment: Please, show a little more detail of what you need to do: give the tables sample names, show sample data, indicate where you create the trigger, and what you want the trigger to do. Or what you need to do if, it's a trigger at all or not.

Comment: table 1 is having AccessLevelCode field

Comment: table 2 is having PageNames; these are multiple records.  So when a user is adding a new AccessLevel to table 1 that AccessLevelCode and all the pages should be inserted into table 3 of UserAccessLevel.

Comment: If table 3 is just containing some data from tables 1 & 2, you might want to consider just using a view. If the data does need to be persisted (general rule of thumb is don't store data you can recalculate), an indexed view might be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You need trigger in both tables? 
It's not possible to loop trigger.. a trigger is an event on a table. You can call a stored procedure and include the result of the trigger with a temporary view